# How to send a message and ignore routing

Tags: go, gmail, gmail-api

I use [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) for sending messages. It works well.
Custom routes are present in the routing tab of gmail advanced settings.

Example of a route: if a sender is **user_a@domain.com** then route his/her messages to **my_smtp_server**

There is bypass list, for users, that can ignore any routing.

I wonder if I can modify this list programmatically or maybe exist any gmail header for that.
The goal is saving the origin *from* header. Because, it's impossible to send message via gmail api from the smtp server, it will be cycling forever.

Graphical visualization of the question.

The diagram starts from the Gmail GUI shape
[Please follow the image link, I cannot use an embedded so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vNfS.png)

Comment: I don't think you can edit other users routes in gmail for obvious privacy/security reasons. If this is internal to your org and you have permission, you can modify a user's filter settings.

Comment: @John, yes it's internal organization. I want to change it programmatically

Comment: Can you please be more explicit with your question? Are you referring to this Google Admin [setting](https://support.google.com/a/answer/77003)? How did you build the current rules? How are you trying to do it at the moment? Please share some examples.

Comment: @Alessandro , yes google admin setting, rules are configured correctly (a pattern line with specific groups mails).I wonder, how to omit routing if you send via gmail API, is it possible? Or maybe you know another way, for example use SMTP protocol instead of Rest for sending, and there are exclusions in the routing configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

### Considerations

Gmail API settings don't allow to edit Email Routing programmatically. [Email Settings](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings) are now deprecated and [these](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings#managing_email_gateway_and_routing) are the only endpoint still available to manage Email Gateway and Routing from Google Admin SDK API. Unfortunately, this API is going through a sun-setting process, you can only edit the routing `accountHandling` parameter with these options:

- **allAccounts** -- Deliver all email to this destination.
- **provisionedAccounts** -- Deliver mail to this destination if the user exists in G Suite.
- **unknownAccounts** -- Deliver mail to this destination if the user does not exist in G Suite. This is similar to the Admin console's 'Delivery email for' setting.

I believe that what you are trying to achieve is **not** possible since there is no way to specify a custom `accountHandling` parameter with the API.

Additionally, since the Routing check is in the Gmail side, your flow will inevitably cause an infinite loop. You should send the email with your own SMTP server to exit the loop.

### References

[Domain settings for email routing](https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?answer=77003).

[Gmail API Email Settings](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings)

[Managing Email Gateway and Routing](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings#managing_email_gateway_and_routing)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following way:

Instead of the Routing settings I used Compliance setting.
And after routing a message, append some header f.e. 'Proxied':1.

The rule for routing is "IF recipients are <...> AND headers don't contain 'Proxied':1

So, it is able to send a mail programmatically without any troubles.